# error while jdk8 installation on ubuntu

Tags: java-8

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-07-18 14:49:48 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I am not able to install jdk any how plz do reply..if any1 understood the error I searhced for it but the steps shown for remedy are not useful its giving me the same error repeatedly

Comment: I would try the OpenJDK 8 as this should have a simpler install. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 0):

@jasmin, its now getting installed, I too was getting the error on my project's travis build. But Now its getting installed. Refer this thread: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9512. It took a day back in April too to get things working again without the user need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way.

Fix for ansible playbook:

```
- name: ORACLE JAVA | Install oracle java from ppa repository  
  apt:
    pkg: "{{ item }}"
    update_cache: yes
    state: latest
    force: yes
  become: true
  become_user: root
  with_items:
    - "oracle-java{{ java_version }}-installer"
    - "oracle-java{{ java_version }}-set-default"
  ignore_errors: yes


- name: ORACLE JAVA | Fix oracle java
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - cd /var/lib/dpkg/info && sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u171|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|' oracle-java8-installer.*
    - cd /var/lib/dpkg/info && sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
    - cd /var/lib/dpkg/info && sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ=.*|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
    - cd /var/lib/dpkg/info && sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_171|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|' oracle-java8-installer.*
  become: true
  become_user: root


- name: ORACLE JAVA | Install oracle java from ppa repository
  apt:
    pkg: "{{ item }}"
    update_cache: yes
    state: latest
    force: yes
  become: true
  become_user: root
  with_items:
    - "oracle-java{{ java_version }}-installer"
    - "oracle-java{{ java_version }}-set-default"
```

Fix for bash:

```
apt-get install  oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default 

cd /var/lib/dpkg/info && sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u171|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ=.*|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_171|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|' oracle-java8-installer.*

apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
```